# iOS Enterprise Build distribution

Tags: ios, enterprise, crashlytics, crashlytics-beta

Is it possible or common to distribute an Enterprise iOS Build with Fabric Crashlytics Beta?

What tools do developers commonly use to distribute Enterprise builds which normally don't require UDID registration and would be downloaded via a link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any host to serve your enterprise builds, as long as your provide a deployment plist file that points to the correct IPA file.

Many services have been created, such as AppBlade, HockeyApp, TestFlight, and now, Beta, to handle these distributions and access. It makes a lot of sense to use these services as they provide an easy release management. For developers, they offer more services, such as automatic crash symbolication and management. If you are already using Crashlytics, it could be beneficial to have the distribution happen from the same place as crash tracking. All services have a free trial which you and your company can test to see if a services gives you the tools you need.